# Query String value not accessible from url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url

When I'm using this URL :

```
http://localhost:3000/case/index?id=14
```

I can access the ID using `params[:id]`

But when the URL is:

```
http://localhost:3000/case/index#tabs-1?id=14
```

The ID value is not accessible using `params[:id]`

Its because of `#tabs-1`. Is there any alternative of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
http://localhost:3000/case/index?id=14#tabs-1
```

The querystring should be immediately after the path.

Comment: Using #tabs-1 after query string fixes the problem ... Thanks for quick reply.